# arrangement of names with same starting alphabets

Tags: java, string

```
public class solution{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String[] priya={"priya","nandhni","nithesh","varan","rekha","sri"};
        System.out.println(priya);
        int n=priya.length;
        for(int i=0,j=i+1;i<n;i++){
           if(priya[i].compareTo(priya[j])>0)
           {
               String temp=priya[i];
               priya[i]=priya[j];
               priya[j]=temp;
           }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println(priya[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output for ascending order comes as

```
nandhni
varan
nithesh
priya
rekha
sri.
```

what could the mistake here?

Comment: Your code is not a complete sort. You only consider directly adjacent pairs of names once.

Comment: Hint: most sort algorithms must involve some sort of nested loop.  Since you only have one loop, the most you can do is one swap per array element (in your case, per adjacent elements).  Start with something simple like a bubble sort, and attempt to [hand execute](https://www.programming4beginners.com/tutorial/chapter04/execution-by-hand) it to understand why one loop isn't enough.

Comment: you want to sort this array (by any way ) you want to make the algorythm of sort ? if you want the algorythme wich kind of algorythme you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Nested loop so that not only adjacent elements are compared and inner loop terminates at last element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (priya[i].compareTo(priya[j]) > 0) {
            String temp = priya[i];
            priya[i] = priya[j];
            priya[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sorting logic is wrong, You are just doing one pass of element comparison

Correct one as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (priya[i].compareTo(priya[j]) > 0) {
            String temp = priya[i];
            priya[i] = priya[j];
            priya[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: stiill not working :(. it gets printed as nandhni
nithesh
priya
varan
rekha
sri

Comment: but **nandhni nithesh priya varan rekha sri** is the correct order?

Comment: No, varan is out of order and should come at the end of the list.